# proper linking of PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH after gcc-5.2 install in own directory

Tags: gcc, graph-tool, gcc5.2

I just compiled and installed gcc-5.2. I did not have root access so I installed it in my own directory. I forget at the end what I am meant to link through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH`

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /bigbang/data/username/lib/gcc-5.2/lib
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /bigbang/data/username/lib/gcc-5.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv PATH /bigbang/data/username/lib/gcc-5.2/bin:$PATH
```

When I simply run `./gcc` I get the following error:

```
gcc: error while loading shared libraries: libiconv.so.2:
```

Is there something wrong with how I am linking the lib paths? Thanks in advance. Also, I simple did configure with `./configure --prefix=/bigbang/data/username/lib/gcc-5.2/`, what is the recommended configuration flags I should use? I'm aiming to use [graph_tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/download).

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully installed GCC with some non-standard prefix
`/my/gcc/prefix` then you can use that installation without any
special preparations by passing:

```
-B/my/gcc/prefix
```

whenever you call the frontend (`gcc`, `g++`, etc). You just call the frontend with the usual command:

```
gcc -B/my/gcc/prefix ...
```

This assumes *some* version of GCC is installed standardly.

See [3.15 Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)

Comment: I didn't do anything non-standard at all. I simple just had --prefix=/path/to/empty/folder/ with no other flags...?

Comment: By 'non-standard prefix' I simply mean not the standard prefix,
which is `/usr.